# How to access original harddisk files in live CD session started using qemu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu

I have 32bit ubuntu OS. On it I download lubuntu OS iso (64 bit). Then I ran qemu command

> qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom image.iso -m 512

After choosing live CD option I can access terminal.

What path do I use to access files on my original harddisk?

I don't see anything under `/media/`

also no directories of the type `/dev/sda` are shown under `/` in the live CD session.

Comment: I have no experience with qemu, but I would assume you should 1) load respective kernel modules for your harddisk (if not done automatically), 2) mknod for its partitions (if not done automatically), 3) create a mount point i.e. /mnt/your_partition and 4) mount desired partition to the mount point with `mount` command.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this can unrecoverable destroy your data! Concurrent writing access to a disk is dangerous.

It is better to transfer files via [nfs or ssh](http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/10/02/how-to-transfer-files-between-host-and-qemu-via-ssh-and-nfs/).
That said, it can be done this way (where '/dev/sdX' is '/dev/sdb' or alike):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom image.iso -m 512 -hda /dev/sdX
```